# Icon on a Pivot

Tags: javascript, html, windows, pivot

I'm starting out in Windows 10 universal App creation going down the Javascript/HTML/CSS route.  I'm looking at Pivots and trying to understand how to get an icon on to tabs along with the text.  And better still style the tabs using CSS.

Sadly nothing seems to work.  I can style the overall Pivot but not the tabs themselves.

```
<body class="win-type-body">
<p>Content goes here</p>
<div id="pivotScenario" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.Pivot" data-win-options="{ title: 'Links', selectedIndex: 1 }">
    <div class="listviewpivotitem" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.PivotItem" data-win-options="{ 'header': 'Link 1', managedLV: true }">
        Link 1
    </div>

    <div class="listviewpivotitem" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.PivotItem" data-win-options="{ 'header': 'Link 2', managedLV: true }">
        Link 2
    </div>

    <div class="listviewpivotitem" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.PivotItem" data-win-options="{ 'header': 'link 3', managedLV: true }">
        Link 3
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I suggest you use DOM Explorer to interrogate the pivot markup.

> Debug > Windows > DOM Explorer > Show All

The pivot control renders out a different markup structure to the one you implement on a page. Using the DOM Explorer will allow you to see the markup that is generated so you can target specific elements and customise it the way you want.

Your pivot control renders out as follows:

```
<div class="win-pivot win-disposable win-element-resize win-pivot-mouse" id="pivotScenario" role="tablist" aria-label="Pivot" data-win-options="{ title: 'Links', selectedIndex: 1 }" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.Pivot">
    <div class="win-pivot-title" style="display: block;">Links</div><div class="win-pivot-header-area"><div class="win-pivot-header-leftcustom"></div><div class="win-pivot-header-items"><div tabindex="0" class="win-pivot-headers" style="margin-right: 0px; margin-left: 12px;"><button tabindex="-1" class="win-pivot-header" role="tab" aria-selected="false" style="margin-right: 12px; margin-left: 12px;" type="button">Link 1</button><button tabindex="-1" class="win-pivot-header win-pivot-header-selected" role="tab" aria-selected="true" style="margin-right: 12px; margin-left: 12px;" type="button">Link 2</button><button tabindex="-1" class="win-pivot-header" role="tab" aria-selected="false" style="margin-right: 12px; margin-left: 12px;" type="button">link 3</button></div></div><div class="win-pivot-header-rightcustom"></div></div><div class="win-pivot-viewport" role="group" style="-ms-scroll-snap-points-x: snapInterval(0%, 1270px);" aria-label="Scrolling Container">
        <div class="win-pivot-surface">
            <div class="listviewpivotitem win-pivot-item win-disposable" role="tabpanel" style="display: none;" data-win-options="{ 'header': 'Link 1', managedLV: true }" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.PivotItem">
                <div class="win-pivot-item-content">
                    Link 1
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="listviewpivotitem win-pivot-item win-disposable" role="tabpanel" style="left: 1270px;" data-win-options="{ 'header': 'Link 2', managedLV: true }" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.PivotItem">
                <div class="win-pivot-item-content">
                    Link 2
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="listviewpivotitem win-pivot-item win-disposable" role="tabpanel" style="display: none;" data-win-options="{ 'header': 'link 3', managedLV: true }" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.PivotItem">
                <div class="win-pivot-item-content">
                    Link 3
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So you could target the `.win-pivot-item-content` class and use the `::before` pseudo class to add your icon. Either that or the `.listviewpivotitem` class of the parent and use background images with padding:

```
.win-pivot-item-content::before {
    content: "";
    background: url(someicon.png) no-repeat;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```